# Eigenvectors of covariance matrix from continuous Lyapunov equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Consider the continuous time Lyapunov equation (with known $A$)
\begin{equation}
A \Theta + \Theta A^\text{T} = -I
\end{equation}
where all matrices are $n\times n$ with real coefficients, $A$ is negative definite with distinct eigenvalues, and $\Theta $ is symmetric and positive definite.

I'm trying to find a (potentially closed-form) relationship between the eigenvectors of $\Theta $ and those of $A$.

If A is symmetric, the Lyapunov equation above has an explicit solution $\Theta =-\frac{1}{2}A^{-1}$ so that $\Theta $ and $A$ are codiagonalisable.

If A is not symmetric, can we find a closed-form solution expressing the eigenvectors of $\Theta$ in terms of the eigenvectors of $A$? I suspect that's not possible, but perhaps some more explicit constraints can be derived by extending one of the approaches in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/246995/469738, which solve for the entries of $\Theta$ rather than its eigenvectors.

Ultimately, I'm interested in the inverse problem of inferring the leading eigenvector of $A$ when $\Theta$ is known, but that has the additional problem that $A$ is not uniquely specified by $\Theta$ in general. In fact, $A$ is only specified up to a skew-symmetric matrix $S$, that is, $A=\Theta^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2}I + S)$. Again, I wonder if there's a more direct way to constrain the leading eigenvector of $A$.

Any insights are appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.